# Spring Controller cannot read the form data string XML correctly

Tags: java, xml, spring, post

We are integrating the webshop with a third party site and thereover, customer adds products to the basket and then the basket submitted to the webshop as form-data `(Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded)`

See the below screenshot of browser, form-data attribute "configuration" holds the data as XML in string format

[image]

Spring controller is written as below, to handle the request but the controller reads the XML without tags and the tag names are replaced with space.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mergebaskets", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String mergeBasket(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {
    String xmlBasket=formData.getFirst("configuration");
        
    LOG.info("000. ########## ORDER CONFIRMATION ########## " +xmlBasket);}
```

Let say if request form data is sent as below

```
<xml><DATA><BASKET><PRODUCT><ID>12341</ID><DESCRIPTION>test prodcut 1</DESCRIPTION></PRODUCT><PRODUCT><ID>12342</ID><DESCRIPTION>test prodcut 2</DESCRIPTION></PRODUCT></DATA></xml>
```

above Spring controller reads and prints as below (without tag names and just values only)

`12341      test prodcut 1      12342      test prodcut 2`

Please help us to make the XML string read correctly.